# Asp.net MVC PagedList Order

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

My problem is exactly the same as this one:
 [toPagedList() order differs from the LINQ order by clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638787/topagedlist-order-differs-from-the-linq-order-by-clause)

That question was posted two years ago and there's no solution yet. I'm hoping someone have answers now. Sorry if this kind of question is not allowed.

EDIT: Here is my LINQ statement

```
(db.Transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.ReservationDate)).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you share your exact LINQ statement? I've got the following code somewhere working without a problem `_repository.Where(condition).OrderByDescending(x => x.Property).ToList().ToPagedList(page, 15);`

Comment: I edited it. Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I dont have idea about ToPagedList() method but you can try that problem this way

```
int? page=1;
            int pageSize = 3; 
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            int numberOfItemsTobeSkipped = (pageNumber-1)  * pageSize;
            var links =( from l in LINKS
                        orderby l.ID descending
                         select l).Skip(numberOfItemsTobeSkipped).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```