# Bigint comparison returing that 100334 is larger than 1002055555

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a column inside my SQL Server 2008 with a data type of `Bigint`.

When I am comparing two numbers such as 1002055555 & 100334 it assumes that 100334 is larger than 1002055555.

Can anyone advice why this is this happening and which data type I should be using to force any comparison to show that 1002055555 is larger than 100334?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the code, I have a PartialTag column of type `Bigint`, and when I did a comparison inside Entity Framewowk such as :

```
var racks = repository.AllFindRacks(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
```

it will return 100205555 before 100334  ..

Bear in mind that EF will translate the Null-able `Bigint` in SQL Server 2008 to be `Nullable<long>` inside my entities class.

Comment: How are you making the comparison? May you show some code?

Comment: i am doing an orderby(a=>a.Bininit) asending. so 1002055555 will come before 100334..

Comment: Post a complete piece of code. Right now this is just an unverifiable blurb.

Comment: see my edit please,, with complete code

Comment: @johnG Looks like these values are converted to `nvarchar` (String value) accidentally before ordering

Comment: @johnG You've put 'I am doing an OrderBy(a => a.Bininit) ascending.' Surely if you're putting them in ascending order then 100334 will come before 1002055555?

Comment: Find out the c# type of `Technology.PartialTag`.

Comment: @Choc13 but in my case 1002055555 will come before 100334 , this is the problem ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman the type is Nullable<long> inside my EF model class.

Comment: @johnG - good, now please add that to the question. It's an important piece of info.

Comment: @johnG Sorry, the way you phrased the question made it sound like you wanted it to return the larger number first, but now I see you mean that this is what it is currently doing.

Comment: @Choc13 now i am sorting ascending by partial tag . so the correct way is to displayed 100334  followed by 1002055555 . but in my case when i am sorting ascending by PartialTag but i am getting 1002055555 followed by 100334  .

Comment: @HenkHolterman added to the original question

Answer (score 1):

Is your repository method `AllFindRacks` calling a stored procedure?  If so, verify no conversion to a string type is happening in there.  The simplest explanation for the results you're seeing would be that at some point your `BigInt` is getting converted to a `varchar` or `nvarchar`.  (Or, that somewhere in the code for `AllFindRacks` a `.ToString()` is happening.)

You might try adding something like this, just to be sure you really are using a `long` by the time it gets to your code:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(racks.First().Technology.PartialTag.GetType().FullName);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, actully i have a feeling that the problem is with the .ToPagedList(page, pagesize);. becuase if i remove the .ToPagedList(page, pagesize) and display the records without paging they will be displayed with the correct order.... not sure why is this and how to solve this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ToPagedList`, but I did find a number of people complaining about `OrderBy` and `ToPagedList` in combination.  One fellow who said he had no problems with it had inserted a `.ToList()` between his `.OrderBy()` and his `ToPagedList()`.  Might be worth a shot.

Comment: The link, FWIW:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028641/asp-net-mvc-pagedlist-order?lq=1

Comment: i added a .Tolist() between orderBy() and ToPagedList(), but it did not solve the problem..