# Sorting a Nullable Biginit is returning wrong sorted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a column inside my sql server 2008 R2 of type Biginit that allow nulls named “Serial”. It has values such as :-:-

```
**Serial**
100200
100202
100375
100376
100377
```

Now inside my asp.net mvc web application, I have the following linq query inside the entity framework :-

```
var records = repository.AllFind(withOutSpace).OrderBy(a => a.Technology.Serial).ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
```

so I am ordering the the records ascending based on the Serial number , but the result was that I got the following order

```
100375
100376
100377
100200
100202
```

So it assumed that 100200 is grater than 100377 !!, any idea what might be causing this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: What type is `repository`?  And what type does A end up being?

Comment: the repository return an IQueryable<> .public IQueryable<Rack> AllFind(string q, bool forautocomplete = false) {}

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code where you might be doing an OrderBy?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a bit more code.  A is of type Rack, and the ordering is done according to the Serial property of the Technology property.  So what type is that?  Is it a nullable long? Or a user-defined type where you had to create your own equals and comparison operators?

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/8638787/282194 has me thinking that perhaps toPagedList() is changing the ordering.  Unfortunately, he never seems to have found (or at least, posted) a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking 100200 as bigger than 100377 then, he is sorting lexicographically, like if the elements were string.

Lexicographycally, 100200 is greater than 100377, and maybe this is the reason.

Comment: but the column is of type biginit and not string !!

Comment: @OscarBralo this is wrong suppose, because if it were true, the results would be: 100377, 100376, 100375, 100202, 100200

Comment: No, lexicographycally sorted will be 100200 because 2 goes before 3, is like when you try to sort strings. "1", "2", "10", the result is "1", "10", "2". ;)